# Why inherited class is not accepecting values

Tags: c#

I'm using Ado.net Entity Framework. Why inherited class was not accepting base class values?

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Access1](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [F_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [L_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Middle_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Gender] [varchar](10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
public abstract class Common
{
    public string F_Name { get; set; }
    public string L_Name { get; set; }      
}
public partial class Access1 : Common
{
    public string Middle_Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

**Home.cs**

1)Here  `"Access1 hh = new Access1();"` does not accepect values from abstract base-class.

2)`hh.F_Name` shows `null` value

```
public ActionResult AbsAssClass(General ss)
{
      Access1 hh = new Access1();
        var access = new Access1
        {
            F_Name=ss.F_Name, L_Name = ss.L_Name 
        };

        db.Access1.Add(access); //An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
}
```

Comment: could u plz hlp me for constructor

Comment: you just initialized hh, `hh.F_Name` would have `NULL` value as that is the default for `string`

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

1. Create a constructor accepting two strings as argument and assign them to your properties:

   ```
   abstract class Common
   {
       public Common(string fName, string lName)
       {
           this.F_Name = fName;
           this.L_Name = lName;
       }
   }
   ```

   For this to work, your derived class needs an (empty) constructor with two arguments that simply redirects to the base-class one:

   ```
   Access(string fName, string lName) : base(fName, lName) { }
   ```
2. Or set the params directly via an object-initializer:

   ```
   var access = new Access { F_Name = anotherValue, L_Name = myValue }
   ```

   This has the advantage that you don´t even need to modify the code of the classes as you don´t need any constructor (in fact you´re just using the default-one and make some assignments after calling it). This is the same as writing this:

   ```
   var access = new Access();
   access.F_Name = myValue;
   access.L_Name = anotherValue;
   ```

Comment: 'ImageWithallCtrls.Models.Common' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: var access = new Access { L_Name = myValue, F_Name = anotherValue }  Here where u declear myValue plz explain this portion

Comment: `myValue` and `anotherValue` are just what you want to assign to the properties. It´s just any arbitrary string-value. As loing as you don´t assign any values to the properties from the base-class they will stay `null`.

Comment: but wen i type  myValue  it give does not exit in context

Comment: This was just an example, I can´t guess from your question what you want the values `F_Name` and `L_Name` to be when you create a new instance of `Access`.